# Iliegal characters in path

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Heres the code with the issue

```
Imports System.Net
Public Class Form1
    Dim wc As New WebClient
    Dim s4 As String
    Dim Ex As Object

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Ex.s4 = wc.DownloadString("Api.com/send.php?ip=" & yolo1.Text & "&port=" & yolo2.Text & "&time=" & yolo3.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub yolo1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles yolo1.TextChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

i changed my text boxed to yolo1,yolo2,and yolo3 because i tried to solve the problem but it didn't work

Comment: Please be more explicit with your issue, what isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the protocol to the URL (eg., http or https):

```
Ex.s4 = wc.DownloadString("http://Api.com/send.php?ip=" & yolo1.Text & "&port=" & yolo2.Text & "&time=" & yolo3.Text)
```